# Can I use cxx.rs types in cbindgen C callback?

Tags: c++, c, rust

I'm trying to embed a small rust lib into my C++ codebase, I use cargo-c(it use cbindgen I think ?) to create some simple C api of rust,  rust side api like this:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" write_result_to_cpp_callback(
    cpp_callback : Option<extern "C" fn(  i64 )>)
```

(it's based on callback instead of returning value because the rust part actually runs a tokio runtime to do the io jobs, and any call to rust is non-blocking)

now I need to pass some complex structure instead of simple i64, seems that cxx.rs makes this simpler, but the cxx.rs function pointer part doc said that

```
Passing a function pointer from C++ to Rust is not implemented yet, only from Rust to an extern "C++" function is implemented.
```

I'd like to know if I can use cxx.rs generated type within my cbindgen C API ? for example

```rust
// for cxx.rs
#[cxx::bridge]
mod ffi{
   struct MyStruct{
      my_vec: Vec<String>
 }
}

// for cbindgen
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" write_result_to_cpp_callback(
    cpp_callback : Option<extern "C" fn( *const ffi::MyStruct )>)
```

and if such usage is OK, will the cbindgen exported api also using the same API as cxx.rs for some container , for example the following code will also work ?

```
// will this Vec have compatible memory layout as I use 
// the cxx.rs generated C++ code ?

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" write_result_to_cpp_callback(
    cpp_callback : Option<extern "C" fn( *const Vec<ffi::MyStruct> )>)

// or I need to also wrap the Vec as a cxx.rs struct member 
// just like following ?

mod ffi{
   struct WrapVec{
      my_vec: Vec<MyStruct>
 }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" write_result_to_cpp_callback(
    cpp_callback : Option<extern "C" fn( *const  WrapVec)>)
```

Thanks for advise

Comment: Have you looked at https://cxx.rs/async.html and https://cxx.rs/binding/vec.html ?

Comment: Thanks for the information, but there's still gaps between examples and my usage, IIUC, async shows C++ fn declared in cxx.rs should recognize cxx.rs built-in type including Vec<T>, but if call it from rust, am I call it directly through ffi (so memory layout is compatible), or calling a cxx.rs wrap fn? , and vec shows rust function can call into C++ and pass rust::Vec<T>, IIRC rust need to mark struct repr(C) to make it compatible with C, but I didn't find wrap type of Vec in rust, so does that mean Vec in rust std default marked with repr(C)?

Comment: As I understand it, `rust::Vec<T>` holds a pointer to a Rust Vec, and each function call calls into Rust to perform that operation on the Vec. Like, `rust_vec.push_back(val)` passes that value to Rust, then calls `vec.push(val)` from the Rust side.

Answer (score 1):

with some digging and help from @PitaJ , I've found the answer to my question

for user declared type, it can be used within cbindgen (even as callback signature) , such type can also include a member which cxx.rs support (for example Vec). because the type itself will be declared as repr(C) , thus the type itself is compatible across ffi boundary. and if such type contains a generic container member (for example Vec), it will be a rust std vec type. you can confirm it by running `cargo expand` (as cxx.rs suggested)

```rust
        #[repr(C)]
        pub struct UserDeclaredType{
            pub vec_member: ::std::vec::Vec<String>
        }
```

since rust std Vec not marked as repr(C), it will have rust(rustc) defined memory layout, which C++ can't understood directly. cxx.rs generated corresponding C++ template class as a dummy wrapper

```
class Vec final {
public:
  ......
private:
  static size_t stride() noexcept;
  void reserve_total(size_t cap) noexcept;
  void set_len(size_t len) noexcept;
  void drop() noexcept;

  std::array<uintptr_t, 3> repr;   
};
```

as you can see, it doesn't contain any C++ meaningful members (I guest it just be same size/aligment as rust vec to make two memory pieces compatible across ffi boundary, since rust vec has ptr/len/capacity 3 members). for every template instantiation, cxx.rs generated a template specialization to dispatch every C++ template function into cxx.rs generated extern C helper function

```
template <>
void Vec<::MyType>::drop() noexcept {
  return cxxbridge1$rust_vec$MyType$drop(this);
}
```

and you can find this cxx.rs generated helper function in rust

```rust
            #[doc(hidden)]
            #[export_name = "cxxbridge1$rust_vec$MyType$drop"]
            unsafe extern "C" fn MyType__vec_drop(
                this: *mut ::cxx::private::RustVec<MyType>,
            ) {
                ::std::ptr::drop_in_place(this);
            }
```

and cxx.rs rust::private::RustVec is a repr(C) wrapper of std Vec

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct RustVec<T> {
    pub(crate) repr: Vec<T>,
}
```

so even user declared type is used as an argument type of a callback in cbindgen, C++ can still understand this type (because it's declared as repr(C)), also the generic container member (because cxx.rs generated wrapped Vec type of this type). thus

```rust
#[cxx::bridge]
mod ffi{
   struct MyStruct{
      my_vec: Vec<String>
 }
}

// for cbindgen
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" write_result_to_cpp_callback(
    cpp_callback : Option<extern "C" fn( *const ffi::MyStruct )>)
```

should be OK. but following callback type

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" write_result_to_cpp_callback(
    cpp_callback : Option<extern "C" fn( *const Vec<ffi::MyStruct> )>)
```

won't work since cbindgen blindly generated a 'Vec template' for the argument without any C++ implementation, so C++ can't understand it (I think you can still mimic what cxx.rs do). so manually wrap the Vec arg as a member of user declared type is still needed (only necessary to make it part of cbindgen signature, and you don't want to mimic what cxx.rs manually)